# How to change css class according to the name attribute of a parent

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown, ui-select

I need your help for a CSS issue. I must change a class on only one element which is created with this : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown

The element is encapsulated in the generated code so I can't give it an id or anything else. 
The only attribute that I can access is in a div (name="OrganizationTypes") which contains the element I need to change.

The generated code looks like this:

```
<div class="ui-select-container ui-select-multiple ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-pristine ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty open ng-touched" 
style="width: 100%; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0" uib-dropdown="" auto-close="outsideClick" 
name="OrganizationTypes" items="vm.availableOrganizationTypes" ng-model="vm.data.organizationTypes" type="text">
<ul class="ui-select-match form-control dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle="" style="margin-bottom:2px;height:auto!important;min-height:31px;" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <!-- ngRepeat: selected in vm.selectedLabel track by selected.path -->
</ul>

<!-- I need to modify dropdown-menu for this ul -->
<ul class="ui-select-choices ui-select-choices-content ui-select-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="width:inherit; overflow:auto; max-height:20em" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    <li class="ui-select-choices-group">
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The boostrap class is defines like this :

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
list-style: none;
background-color: #fff;
background-clip: padding-box;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
}
```

and I need to change the position to relative.

How can I achieve this this ? I need to redefine a new dropdown-menu but I don't know how the selector. I'm absolutely incompetent in CSS :(

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but I think you are looking for the `[attribute=value]` selector.

Here you can find examples [CSS [attribute=value] Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_attribute_value.asp)

In your case, I think you should build a selector like this:

```
div[name=OrganizationTypes] .dropdown-menu {
   position: relative;
}
```

Tell us if it is what you are looking for =)

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for and it works. Thank you.